# How to put multiple items in dataTextField as it is in itemTemplate?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have an item template in my Kendo multiselect as followed:

```
itemTemplate: "#= Code# #='-'# #= Name#",
   dataTextField: "Code"
```

How can I have both the name and the code in dataTextField?

I'd appriciate if you could help me?

Best,
Marjan

Answer (score 0):

Reference: From **[Kendo UI Docs for MultiSelect](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/template)**, and [Angular Kendo MultiSelect](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/angular) define `itemTemplate` as follow.

```
$scope.myMultiSelect = {
     ...
     dataTextField: "Name",
     dataValueField: "Code",
     itemTemplate: "#: data.Code # - #: data.Name #"
     ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`dataTextField` can only point to a **single** data item field.

By using [`itemTemplate`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#configuration-itemTemplate) and [`tagTemplate`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#configuration-tagTemplate) you can use multiple fields simultaneously in the dropdown and selected tags.

If this is not good enough, you will have to create a new data item field, which contains all the information you need, and then use that field as `dataTextField`.

Comment: Thanks for your responce. But the reason I want to have multiple itmes in the dataTextField is that I want to be able to filter the multiselect based on either Code or Name. So the user can type either of them and they will be filtered. Do you think it is possible?